# WooCommerce: Create products pages instead of using product filter

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filter, seo

I am developping a webshop, with filters linked to some attributes.

When I click on a filter, Woocommerce reload the page with the filter in the Url ([www.x.com/?filter_y=z](http://www.x.com/?filter_y=z)) and the right products on the pages.

How can I do to:

- create a "real" page instead of filtered page, with a URL [www.x.com/z/](http://www.x.com/z/) (or www.x/com/y/z, does not matter). Title and H1 should be customisable
- having a crawlable link inside filters that redirect to [www.x.com/z/](http://www.x.com/z/)

I checked plugins like Premmerce that did not do the job (and lack of tutorial).

Any idea to do it by ourselves?

Comment: You can simply use [Woocommerce `[products]` shortcode](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-9) or use WooCommerce Gutenberg blocks in your pages

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do you replace the page "created" by the filtering (www.x.com/?filter_y=z) with the newly created page inside the filters?

Comment: You can try to use for example [the `template_redirect` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwoocommerce%5D+template_redirect+redirection) and redirect user based on Url query string like `if ( isset($_GET['filter_y']) && $_GET['filter_y']  === 'z' ) { wp_redirect( $your_page_url ); exit(); }` where `$your_page_url`is the related page URL

Comment: Ok, I will try it. We agree that the link inside the filters would unfortunately still be like www.x.com/?filter_y=z ?

Comment: Yes but they will be redirected to the related page, where you will use a shotcode to display the products.

Comment: Thank you again!